# Problem in extracting data using a for-loop in Julia

Tags: for-loop, indexing, julia

I'm trying to extract data from a structure object called X using a for-loop as follows.

Is that possible using julia? To make things clearer, X is the name of the tree, solution is one level, bus is another level, the number of buses are under bus, under each bus number, we have two variables, vm and va. How to extract such data?

Regards

```
for i=1:30
Mag(i)=X["solution"]["bus"]["i"]["vm"];
Ang(i)=X["solution"]["bus"]["i"]["va"];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide a fully reproducible example to be sure, but assuming `Mag` and `Ang` are vectors and `X` was originally created from JSON (which means that its keys are strings) this is how you could write it:

```
for i=1:30
    Mag[i]=X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["vm"]
    Ang[i]=X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["va"]
end
```

**EDIT**

Given your comments probably this is the simplest thing you can do:

```
Mag = [X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["vm"] for i in 1:30]
Ang = [X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["va"] for i in 1:30]
```

And you do not have to define these variables earlier then.

Comment: I tried this and I still get an error, the error is LoadError: UndefVarError: Mag not defined
in expression starting at C:\Users\Abd-PC\Desktop\testing PowerModels\testing_PowerModels:4
top-level scope at testing_PowerModels:5 [inlined]
top-level scope at none:0

Comment: You have to define `Mag` first before assigning to it. Please copy-paste your whole relevant code, as if you show only part of it it is hard to help.

Comment: I'm using a library called "powermodels" and the whole code is


    using PowerModels; using Ipopt;
    X=run_ac_opf("pglib_opf_case30_ieee.m", IpoptSolver());
    for i=1:30
            Mag[i]=X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["vm"]
            Ang[i]=X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["va"]
    end

Comment: I have modified my code to be

        using PowerModels; using Ipopt;
        X=run_ac_opf("pglib_opf_case30_ieee.m", IpoptSolver());
        Mag=float64[];
        Ang=float64[];
        for i=1:30
           Mag[i]=X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["vm"]
           Ang[i]=X["solution"]["bus"]["$i"]["va"]
        end 

However, I still get the following error
LoadError: UndefVarError: float64 not defined

I'm frustrated by dealing with this language. How come float64 needs to be defined!

Comment: You should write `Float64` not `float64`, which is explained in the Julia Manual here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Integers-and-Floating-Point-Numbers-1. Also in this case you should rather write e.g. `Mag=zeros(30)` and `Ang=zeros(30)`. I will add another option you can use in the answer as it is more verbose.